# Proving two complex integrals give the same result.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $a,b \in \mathbb C, a \neq 0$ and $T: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$, $T(z)=az+b$. Given a curve $\gamma$ and  $c \not \in \gamma$, prove that
$$\int_{T \circ \gamma} \dfrac{dz}{z-T(c)}=\int_{\gamma} \dfrac{dz}{z-c}$$

I am not sure how to prove this, all I know is that

$$\int_{T \circ \gamma} \dfrac{dz}{z-T(c)}=\int_{T \circ \gamma} \dfrac{dz}{z-ac+b}$$

how could I continue from here?

Comment: Cauchy integral formula / residue theorem.

Comment: Notice these curves are not closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$.
By computing directly one verifies that:$$\int_{T \circ \gamma} \dfrac{dz}{z-T(c)}=\int_0^1\frac{T'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)}{T(\gamma(t))-T(c)}dt=\int_0^1\frac{a\gamma'(t)}{a(\gamma(t)-c)}dt=\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z-c},$$
since $T'\equiv a$, and $T(w)-T(z)=a(w-z)$.

Comment: Just to be hypercorrect: $dt$s are missing. ;)